# How do I maintain associations for a deleted object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have an object `PortStock`, which I keep track of via `OrderHistory`. i.e. every time a specific action is taken on a `port_stock` object, I create an `order_history` object associated with that `port_stock`.

Think of `OrderHistory` as a transaction history on that specific `PortStock`.

The issue now is, when I delete a `PortStock` object, I still want to be able to retrieve (and display) all the `order_history` objects associated with that `PortStock` record.

This is how I currently do it, which doesn't work when `@port_stock` has been deleted:

```
@port_stock = current_user.port_stocks.friendly.find(params[:id])
@stock = @port_stock.stock
@order_histories = OrderHistory.joins(:port_stock).where(port_stocks: { ticker: @stock.ticker}).group_by { |o| o.port_stock }
```

Thoughts?

**Edit 1**

My `PortStock` model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: port_stocks
#
#  id                :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  portfolio_id      :integer
#  stock_id          :integer
#  volume            :integer
#  action            :integer
#  position          :integer          default("open")
#  ticker            :string
#

class PortStock < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :ticker
  belongs_to :portfolio
  belongs_to :stock
  has_many :order_histories

  enum action: [ :buy, :sell ]
  enum position: [ :open, :closed ]
end
```

My `OrderHistory` model looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: order_histories
#
#  id                :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  port_stock_id     :integer
#  num_units         :integer
#  action            :integer
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#

class OrderHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :port_stock
  enum action: [ :buy, :sell ]
end
```

Comment: what are you schema and model relationships like ?

Comment: @Subash refresh the page to see the updated question with that info.

Comment: maybe I don't understand your questions, do orderhistory get deleted when portstock is deleted, I don't see cascade deletes defined, when portstock is deleted how do you plan to query the orderhistory, it only belongs to portstock ?

Comment: @Subash `Orderhistory` does not get deleted when `portstock` is. But you do get what I am asking. That question about how do I query the `orderhistory` after the `port_stock` it belongs to is gone. How do I do that?

Comment: I just don't understand the use case, where do you need to show the oderhistory, since there is no relationship to anything else, either you need to maintain the ids of portstock to query or you can soft delete portstock and set it to inactive to always have the relationship alive

Comment: what is the purpose of enum `position: [ :open, :closed ]` in the PortStock model? Either this, or something else like it, could be used to toggle the status...instead of deleting PortStock objects as @Subash said.

Comment: Hrmm...good point. Yeah....it is supposed to indicate whether a `port_stock` is opened or closed. I was just doing a `.destroy`, but maybe I should just set the `position: :closed` and effectively do a soft-delete per Subash's recommendation. That does make sense.